# How to get element to float inside of body instead of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image that is floating around inside of a div using javascript. The div is in the first section of a page on a long scroll. So the image bounces around in the first div, but when I scroll down it stays in that div. I want the image move down the page ( in the body ) as the user scrolls down and the image bounces off the browser window and using browser window as reference, not the container div as seen below in code.

I have tried to put the div in the body, but I think it has to do with the javascript.

the image is essentially trapped inside of the `container-fluid`.Taking it out of that container and changing the x and y of the script to `$(window).width()` and $(window).width() isn't doing the trick.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="section-1-new">
           <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/image.png"></a></li>
       </div>
</div> 

<script>
$.fn.bounce = function(options) {

    var settings = $.extend({
        speed: 10
    }, options);

    return $(this).each(function() {

        var $this = $(this),
            $parent = $this.parent(),
            height = $parent.height(),
            width = $parent.width(),
            top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height / 2)) + height / 4,
            left = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width / 2)) + width / 4,
            vectorX = settings.speed * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1),
            vectorY = settings.speed * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1);

        // place initialy in a random location
        $this.css({
            'top': top,
            'left': left
        }).data('vector', {
            'x': vectorX,
            'y': vectorY
        });

        var move = function($e) {

            var offset = $e.offset(),
                width = $e.width(),
                height = $e.height(),
                vector = $e.data('vector'),
                $parent = $e.parent();

            if (offset.left <= 0 && vector.x < 0) {
                vector.x = -1 * vector.x;
            }
            if ((offset.left + width) >= $parent.width()) {
                vector.x = -1 * vector.x;
            }
            if (offset.top <= 0 && vector.y < 0) {
                vector.y = -1 * vector.y;
            }
            if ((offset.top + height) >= $parent.height()) {
                vector.y = -1 * vector.y;
            }

            $e.css({
                'top': offset.top + vector.y + 'px',
                'left': offset.left + vector.x + 'px'
            }).data('vector', {
                'x': vector.x,
                'y': vector.y
            });

            setTimeout(function() {
  move($e);
}, 0);

vectorX = settings.speed * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 0.1 : -0.1),
vectorY = settings.speed * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 0.1 : -0.1);

            };

        move($this);
    });

};

$(function() {
    $('.section-1-new li').bounce({
        'speed': 1.8
    });
});
```

Comment: can you try changing this: $parent = $this.parent(), to $parent = $(document) ?

Comment: @klikas it made it hide underneath a random element in the middle of the page.

Comment: if it does bounce as you want, without being confined by the parent but happens to hide from times to times, this is a separate, z-index issue.

Comment: @klikas it for sure frees it from the parent, but it's not bouncing off of the browser window, and stays in a horizontal area when I scroll up or down.

var $this = $(this),
            $parent = $(document),
            height =  $(window).width(),
            width =  $(window).height(),
            top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height / 2)) + height / 4,
            left = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width / 2)) + width / 4,
            vectorX = settings.speed * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1),
            vectorY = settings.speed * (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1);

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the CSS as such:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
```

Comment: You are suggesting replacing $this.css({}) portion?

Answer (score 0):

I just put `postion:fixed` on the img div and it did the trick.

```
    .section-1-new li a img {
        width: 420px;
        height: auto;
        z-index: 1000001;
        position: fixed;

}
```